# Call iPhone Photo Library on WebView Button Click

Tags: iphone, html, webview, onclick

How can I call the iPhone Photo Library when an HTML button element (e.g., `<input type="button">`) is clicked in a WebView? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to call a custom url like

```
open:\\imageBrowser
```

Then in the UIwebViewDelegate catch this URL and open the Photo library picker:

```
- (BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
   if ([[[request URL] absoluteURL] isEqualToString:@"open:\\imageBrowser"] {
      // open the image picker
   }
}
```

Comment: One little comment. You should use absoluteString instead of absoluteURL to compare a string.